# How to use defmacro instead of eval?

Tags: macros, clojure, eval, clojurescript

I have come up with the below function, which works as intended but it uses eval which is horrible, and does not exist in ClojureScript where i intend to use it.

```
(defn path [d p]
  (eval 
    (concat '[-> d] 
      (flatten (map 
                 #(conj (repeat (dec %) 'z/right) 'z/down) 
                 (path-to-vector p))))))
```

How would I convert it to a macro? My attempt looks like this:

```
(defmacro path [d p]
  `(concat (-> ~d)
      (flatten
       (map #(conj (repeat (dec %) z/right) z/down)
             (path-to-vector ~p)))))
```

But that clearly does not work.

Comment: To begin with, no need to use concat inside the syntax-quote. Your macro will probably look something like: `(-> d ~@(flatten ...))

Comment: Your macro will depend on its usage, are d and p values that are available at compile time or are they runtime thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a macro or eval, the operation is just a `reduce`:

```
(defn path [d p]
  (reduce (fn [s v]
            (reduce #(%2 %1) s (conj (repeat (dec v) z/right) z/down)))
          d (path-to-vector p)))
```

Also note that `(conj (repeat (dec %) z/right) z/down)` means z/down and then all the z/right coz repeate return a sequence, in case you want all z/right first and last item should be z/down then you should use `(conj (vec (repeat (dec %)) z/right) z/down)`

Answer (score 1):

Ankur is correct that this is a case for reduce and neither a macro or eval is appropriate, though it's perhaps still worth explaining the mechanics of writing a macro such as this for it's own sake:

Your macro example is very close, all you need is the splicing-unquote function to make it work:

```
(defmacro path [d p]
  `(-> ~d 
      ~@(flatten
         (map #(conj (repeat (dec %) z/right) z/down)
               (path-to-vector ~p)))))
```

this evaluates the call to flatten at macro expansion time and then concatenates it into the resulting s-expression/list.

Comment: You dont need concat, just `(-> ~d ~@(flatten ...))

Comment: This is true :) I was trying to stay as close to the original as possible. I'll fix that.